Wrapping an element with an <a> that has a dynamic href jQuery
Got a series of list items, and I'm trying to wrap the content with links and add a dynamic href. It's wrapping the list item contents properly, but it's adding the href to the list item instead. What's wrong with my syntax here?
jQuery:
$('.menu ul li').each(function(i, e){
$(this).wrapInner('<a></a>').attr("href", "#" + "slide-" + i);
});

Base HTML:
<nav class="menu">
<ul>
<li>Child 1</li>
</ul>
</nav>

Current output for the list items:
<li href="#slide-0">
<a>Child 1</a>
</li>


Right.  You'll have to do the wrap, then fetch the inner tag, and modify that.  Or, better, something like wrapInner('<a href=#slide'+i+'></a>').

wrapInner returns the object that called it, not the inner object created. You can either find that (i.e., .wrapInner('<a></a>').find('a').attr("href", `#slide-${i}`);) but remember you're now on the anchor, not the list item, if you chain further, or you can just add it to the HTML directly, as @TimRoberts has shown.

.wrapInner() returns the element that was wrapped, not the wrapping element.
Create the <a> element and add the attribute to that, then wrap that around the element.


$('.menu ul li').each(function(i, e) {
  $(this).wrapInner($('<a>', {
    "href": "#" + "slide-" + i
  }));
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Child 1</li>
  </ul>
</nav>




Beautiful. Thanks.
